# Can't install Synaptic or Grace on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: synaptic

I've tried installing through `sudo apt-get install` and software center for both Synaptic and Grace (a plotting tool). For `sudo apt-get install`, I get

```
E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
```

and for the software center I'm getting:

```
there isn't a software package called "grace" in youc current software sources
```

I have "main", "universe", "restricted", and "multiverse" checked for software sources. I'm an ubuntu noob. Thanks!

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update`, then try installing your packages again.

Comment: I've tried that as well to no avail, but thanks!

Comment: Please put the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal type this:

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main"`

and than type

`sudo apt-get update`

after this you should be able to install synaptic through software centre

Comment: BTW i use this on my 13.04 testing setup

Comment: Thanks apfelsine. I gave this a shot, but no luck! Any other thoughts?

Comment: looks like something is broken there, the easiest way you can always reinstall ubuntu